# If $\frac{x-1}{e^x-1} = y$ then $x=?$

Tags: calculus, logarithms, exponential-function, transcendental-equations, lambert-w

I have following equation:

$$\frac{x-1}{e^x-1} = y$$

I want to solve this equation such that I have the value of $x$ in the term of $y.$ i.e. inverse of the equation

Comment: Is it $e^{x-1}$ or $e^x-1$?

Comment: it's second one i.e. ((e^x)-1)

Comment: you want the inverse function?

Comment: Apparently, you cannot obtain $x$ as an elementary function of $y$.

Comment: @Essam yes I want inverse function

Comment: Perhaps you need a Lambert W function? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function

Comment: @Arpan can you give some explanation ?

Comment: @Vijay13 Read the link posted by Phill

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%3D%28x-1%29%2F%28e%5Ex-1%29+inverse is your solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint.** You may transform the equation
$$
\frac{x-1}{e^x-1} = y \tag1
$$ with a little algebra into
$$
-(x+y-1)e^{-(x+y-1)}=-ye^{1-y},\tag2
$$ set $X:=-(x+y-1)$ obtaining
$$
Xe^X=-ye^{1-y} \tag3
$$ then use the [Lambert function W](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) to get

> $$
> x=1-y-W\left(-ye^{1-y}\right). \tag4
> $$

Comment: +1 for lambert W function. Seems to be everywhere I go now.

Comment: @IrrationalPerson. Yes, it is more and more used and there are even *generalized* Lambert functions too which allows solving very complex equations. .